# Excel- compare two cell from different sheet, if true copy value from other cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

So, I have a worksheet A and worksheet B.

I would like to compare column A on both sheets with each other.

If the value is the same (true), than copy value from worksheet B, from column F (this value is email address, and it is of course different in every row).

I tried with VLOOKUP, but I cannot figure it out. My excel knowledge is quite poor.

Any help please. Thanks

EDIT:
I want to check company names in first sheet against all of the company names in the other sheet. And for those which are the same, copy the emails (which I have only in sheet2)

Comment: If the answer given by OptimizedQuery isn't what you were looking for, you might try posting some sample data and explain what your expected result would be if run on that data.

Answer (score 3):

In your destination field you want to use VLOOKUP like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet2!A1:F100,6,FALSE)
```

VLOOKUP Arguments:

1. The set fields you want to lookup.
2. The table range you want to lookup up your value against.  The first column of your defined table should be the column you want compared against your lookup field.  The table range should also contain the value you want to display (Column F).
3. This defines what field you want to display upon a match.
4. FALSE tells VLOOKUP to do an exact match.

Comment: Hm, I do not even know anymore if the vlookup is the right function. I want to check company names in first sheet against all of the company names in the other sheet. And for those which are the same, copy the emails (which I have only in sheet2)