# Excel 2010, highlight cells if they match cells in another column

Tags: excel, ms-office

Simple one really, how do I highlight cells in column A if their value appears in column B? I found a thread that does the opposite:

[Change the color of cells in one column when they don't match cells in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189260/change-the-color-of-cells-in-one-column-when-they-dont-match-cells-in-another-c)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, simple one really. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396677/excel-compare-two-cell-from-different-sheet-if-true-copy-value-from-other-cell

Comment: I've also tried the various google suggestions i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345379/conditional-formatting-cells-if-their-value-equals-any-value-of-another-column or https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/26/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/ but none seem to just simply highlight a cell if it appears in another column

Comment: How do you want to compare your data in the columns?? add screenshots if your data here

Comment: I can't add screenshots due to confidentiality but it's something like:http://imgur.com/5RXgPrl and I just want to highlight cells in A if they appear in B

Comment: Is there not a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Select column A
- Select conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "use formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter the formula `=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=1` in the formula bar
- Select a color to highlight and press OK